# What is the time complexity of nested loop over single loop with same task

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

So, what is the difference between given below two function in terms of performance and what is the time complexity of both function. It is doing exactly same task with two loop and single loop.

With TWO Loop.

```
  RecipeModel returnRecipe(String? suggestion) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _appData.recipeCategories!.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < _appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes!.length; j++) {
        if (_appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes![j].recipeName! ==
            suggestion) {
          return _appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes![j];
        }
      }
    }
    return recipe;
  }
```

With Single loop

```
RecipeModel returnRecipe(String? suggestion) {
    int recCategoriesLen = _appData.recipeCategories!.length;
    int i = 0
    for (int j = 0; j < _appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes!.length;) {
        if (_appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes![j].recipeName! ==
        suggestion) {
            return _appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes![j];
        }
        j++
        if (_appData.recipeCategories![i].recipes!.length == j && i < recCategoriesLen - 1) {
            i++
            j = 0
        }
    }
    return recipe;
}
```

Comment: Each is linear in the number of recipes, but the first is much more straightforward. The second is clever in a bad way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common for people, when first learning about big-O notation, to assume that big-O notation is calculated by looking at how many loops there are and then multiplying those loops together in some way. While that's often the case, the real guiding principle behind big-O analysis is to think through, conceptually, what it is that the loops are actually doing.

In your case, you have a 2D array of items indexed by i and j. The first version of the code explicitly enumerates all pairs of possible i's and j's, with the outer loop visiting all choices of i and the inner loop visiting all choices of j. The total work done is then proportional to the number of items visited.

The second loop does essentially the same thing, but less explicitly. Specifically, it still generates all possible combinations of i and j, except that there's just a single loop driving the changes to both i and j. Because you're still iterating over all choices, the amount of work done is likely to be pretty similar to what you started with. The actual performance will depend on what optimizations the compiler/interpreter does for you.

To actually reduce the amount of work you're doing, you'll need to find a fundamentally different strategy. Since you're asking the question "across all combinations of i and j, does this item exist?," you might want to store an auxiliary hash table (dictionary) that stores each recipe keyed by its name. That way, you don't need to loop over everything and can instead just do a dictionary lookup, which is much faster.